# Save QTextDocument into docx using python-docx

Tags: python, pyqt, python-docx

Is there a library that already parses through the QTextBlocks from a  QTextDocument and converts them to add_paragaph and add_run calls for python-docx. I would like to save snippets a user created in QTextDocuemnt into my docx output, it seems like this is something some one has already done. Perhaps its a feature of python-docx I cannot find?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a poor mans parser I wrote. Its not pretty but I think it shows the principles if you wanted to write a more complete and robust version

````
    @staticmethod
    def convertDocument(docx:Document, qtd: QTextDocument) -> Document:
        retVal = Document()
        block = qtd.begin()
        while block is not None:
            Convert.convertBlock(docx, block)
            if block == qtd.end():
                block = None
            else:
                block = block.next()
        return retVal

    @staticmethod
    def convertBlock(docx:Document, block: QTextBlock):
        textlist = block.textList()
        style = None
        indent = False
        if textlist is not None:
            listformat = textlist.format()
            bulletTypes = [QTextListFormat.ListDisc, QTextListFormat.ListCircle, QTextListFormat.ListSquare]
            if listformat.style() in bulletTypes:
                style = 'List Bullet'
            else:
                style = 'List Number'
            indent = True

        p = docx.add_paragraph("", style)
        text = block.text()
        for frange in block.textFormats():
            r = p.add_run(text[frange.start:(frange.start+frange.length)])
            if frange.format.hasProperty(QTextFormat.FontPointSize):
                r.font.size = Pt(frange.format.doubleProperty(QTextFormat.FontPointSize))

            if frange.format.hasProperty(QTextFormat.FontWeight):
                weight = frange.format.intProperty(QTextFormat.FontWeight)
                if weight > 50:
                    r.font.bold = True

        if indent:
            p.paragraph_format.left_indent = Inches(0.70)
        return p
    ```
````